# List of Updates available in TexLive utility the same every time

Tags: texlive, mac

For some reason I keep getting the same available updates every time I open TexLive Utility. I update all of them (200mb worth of updates) and after getting the message that it was successful, I close TexLive, and when I open again the same updates are there available as if I had not just updated them.

I am using TexLive Utility Version 1.17, on Mac OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: Have you tried using the command line version (`sudo tlmgr update --self --all`) to see if you get the same result?

Comment: @Mico that seems to work, thanks. This though seems more like a workaround than a solution. Do you know how I can make TexLive utility work properly again? Any clue as to what the problem might be? I have reinstalled TexLive utility from the dropdown menu but that did not work.

Comment: @Vivi In `~/Library/Application Support/TeX Live Utility` there is a file called `Log Messages.plist`.  Try moving that to the trash and trying again. Alternatively, Adam Maxwell is active on the TeX on MacOS mailing list, so you might want to ask there for this particular question.

Comment: @AlanMunn I moved the file to the trash. I need to wait until there are new updates to see if this solution works or not, and when I have an answer I will post here again. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanMunn your solution worked. Could you please post is as an answer?

Comment: I wish I'd seen this last year, since it sounds like an interesting problem, and I'd like to fix it in TeX Live Utility. Asking a question like this via email to tlu@tug.org or the Mac OS X TeX list would have been helpful, as Alan Munn pointed out. The main reason I'm posting here is to ask that users **do not** delete `~/Library/Application Support/TeX Live Utility/Log Messages.plist`, since it has all the information needed to debug problems like this. I cannot think of any circumstances under which you should delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `~/Library/Application Support/TeX Live Utility` there is a file called `Log Messages.plist`. Move that to the trash and try again.

**Update:**

It appears that this is not likely to solve the problem (or any problem) according to Adam Maxwell, the developer of TeX Live Utility, so I can no longer endorse this answer. I'll keep it here, however to give context to Adam's answer.

I should also note the moving the `.plist` file to the trash doesn't permanently delete it unless you empty the trash, so recovering it for debugging purposes will generally not be a problem.

Comment: Actually, it seems like it isn't working. I will have to contact the person you mentioned.

Comment: @Vivi sorry to hear that. Feel free to "unaccept" the answer.  But an email to the MacTeX list might then be the best solution.

Comment: it seems like it could have to do with the internet at uni. When I do it from home it works, when I do using the university internet it doesn't. I subscribed to the list but I will investigate further before asking them a question.